# How to sign DLL with certificate in Visual Studio (SQL Server CLR)

Tags: deployment, certificate, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I try to sign the CLR assembly in Visual Studio database project (SSDT) so that I can publish the assembly into the SQL Server but with no success.

### What I have done manually and it works

1. Created certificate in SQL Server and exported it
2. Then I converted the certificate format PVK to PFX

```bash
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk C:\Certs\ClrCert.pvk -spc C:\Certs\ClrCert.cer -pfx C:\Certs\ClrCert.pfx -pi Pa$$w0rd -po Pa$$w0rd
```

3. Signed the DLL with the PFX certificate

DLL is located in the BIN folder of the Visual Studio project.

```bash
signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /f C:\Certs\ClrCert.pfx /p Pa$$w0rd C:\...\bin\Release\ClrTest.dll
```

4. Imported signed assembly and executed it

```sql
-- Import assembly
CREATE ASSEMBLY CLRTest FROM 'C:\...\CLRTest.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO

-- Import function from the assembly
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FooFunction] (@year INT NULL)
RETURNS BIT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [CLRTest].[UserDefinedFunctions].[FooFunction]

-- Execute function
select dbo.FooFunction(2022)
```

### Attempt 1 - Sign an assembly in post build event

1. Setup event

`Project > Properties > Build events : Post-build event command line`

```bash
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /fd SHA256 /f C:\Certs\ClrCert.pfx /p Pa$$w0rd "C:\Workspace\CLRTest\bin\Release\ClrTest.dll"
```

2. Hit build

I can see in the Output window that DLL was signed

```
Done Adding Additional Store Successfully signed:
C:\Workspace\CLRTest\bin\Release\CLRTest.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

2. Deploy

When I execute publish profile I see this error

```
CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'CLRTest' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. 
Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key...
```

why is that?

### Attempt 2 - Sign an assembly with Visual Studio wizard

1. Open window

`Project > Properties > SQLCLR > Signing`

2. Select certificate and provide a password

[image]

3. Hit build

I get this error that the key cannot be imported

```
Cannot import the following key file: ..\..\..\..\..\Certs\ClrCert.pfx. The key file may be password protected.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem, just couldn't assign the c# CLR project in Visual Studio, even followed all the googled solutions.

It turned out there is very simple way:

**Just create the pfx file in visual studio**, pick '<New...>' in the "Choose a strong name key file" drop down.